# Why should the past simple tense be used in this case?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs

In the following sentences, the past simple tense is used after the present perfect tense. Both sentences are connected with each other:

> I **have been** hit by a baseball bat in the past. It **felt** awful!

My question is: Why is the past simple *("felt")* used instead of the present perfect *("has felt")*?

Comment: Because the first verb tells you it's in the past without specifying when (one of the uses of the PP) and the second tells you it's a done thing i.e. over. It does not continue to feel awful at the time of speaking. It felt awful when it happened.

Comment: @Lambie What about _Whenever I've been hit by a baseball bat in the past, it has felt awful_? Here PP(_has felt_) sounds correct.

Comment: @user405662 It's grammatical, but native speakers tend to avoid perfect tense when it's not necessary. So "Whenever I've been ... it felt awful" is idiomatic.